# On click of page overlay i want popup to get close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on page overlay for the first time the popup gets close. When I refresh the page again the popup doesn't close on click of page overlay.

You can check here on the demo website: http://gomodemo.se/hk-sandbox/

```
I tried following jQuery
jQuery("#pum-3968").click(function($){
     jQuery("#popmake-3968").hide();
     jQuery("#footera").show();
    });

jQuery("#footera").click(function($){
     jQuery("#popmake-3968").show();
     jQuery("#footera").hide();
    });
```

Comment: Yelling ASAP does help you

Comment: U can check here on the demo website http://gomodemo.se/hk-sandbox/

Comment: The popup did close 2nd, 3rd and nth time as well. It is the overlay that wasn't closing in your demo.

Comment: @nightgaunt : I want everytime if someone click on overlay the popup should get close. It is happening but when the user clicks for the first time on overlay the popup is closing.

Comment: I hope I understand the terms popup and overlay correctly. `#popmake-3968` is popup. `#pum-3968` is overlay. When you click on `#pum-3968` the `#popmake-3968` gets closed. It is working in your demo. The only difference I observed is that first time, `#pum-3968` also gets hidden. Subsequent times, only `#popmake-3968` is hidden. Now, if your question is about closing popup, your code is correct and working.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code

```
<script>
    $(window).click(function(e) {
       e = e || event;
       var target = $(e.target) || (e.srcElement);
       //myid is the id of overlay
       if(target.is('#myid')){
        target.hide();
       }
  });
</script>
```

if you give me your html code ,I can be more helpful.